# How to change sort order of image gallery in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, frontend, product-images, media-images

i'm using magento 2 defualt image gallery. I'm trying to change to sort order of image. [image]

I need this active image to come first in the left image sidebar.

```
public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {
        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                'caption' => $image->getLabel(),
                'position' => '500',
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
            ];
        }

        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }
```

This is the default code. where to change the order of image. thanks in advanced

Comment: You have it right there. `position `

Comment: on which bases you need to sort images ?

Comment: I tried changing positions but no use. I need the second image to come first and the first illustration to be second.

Comment: @RameshKR did you get the answer?